# Unity2D camera zoom out by the distance of player to an object, Zoom in when it gets further away

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale

I'm working on a side-scroller 2D plataform game, and I have a moment where there's a focus in the background in which i want to show to the player for an "aw" moment, and i want to zoom out the camera to show that moment and then zoom back in again. I guess you could say to do the same like Death's Gambit or hollow Knight when the object they want to show is too big for the size of the camera.

Tried to get the transform from the player in a certain area and calculate the distance to the point where i want the camera size to go to the max, and then calculate a percentage out of it to add multiplied by size difference but it would break the view port making it spazz out or zooming out to the max unity allowed.

The expected result is to make the camera zoom out with the distance to a certain point in the world, passing that point it stops zooming out, going backwards should zoom back in to the player with the initial OrtographicSize.

Thank you for the Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
public Transform Target1;
public Transform Target2;

public float sensetivity = 1f;
public float maxOrthographicSize = 10f;

Camera thisCam;
float minOrthographicSize = 5f;

private void Start() {
    thisCam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    minOrthographicSize = thisCam.orthographicSize;
}
void Update()
{
    thisCam.orthographicSize = minOrthographicSize + Mathf.Clamp(Vector2.Distance(Target1.position, Target2.position) * sensetivity, 0f, maxOrthographicSize);
}
```

In this solution `minOrthographicSize` can only happen if `Target1` and `Target2` are in the same position, to change that you can do:

```
public Transform Target1;
public Transform Target2;

public float minOrhtographicDistance = 5f;
public float sensetivity = 1f;
public float maxOrthographicSize = 10f;

Camera thisCam;
float min = 5f;

private void Start() {
    thisCam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    min = thisCam.orthographicSize;
}
void Update()
{
    thisCam.orthographicSize = min + Mathf.Clamp((Vector2.Distance(Target1.position, Target2.position) - minOrhtographicDistance) * sensetivity, 0f, maxOrthographicSize);
}
```

In this solution, the orthographic size will be `minOrthographicSize` for `minOrhtographicDistance` distance and then would change depending on the distance between targets.

Comment: I had to do some adjustments to the code and take out the public's that weren't necessary and put them with a serialize field, nonetheless it works wonders. Thank you for the help!